# Birth Record of Christian Paap born 1835 Mecklenburg

Tags: germany, birth-records

I am looking for the birth of Christian Paap, born 15 Sep 1835 according to USA records. He married Dorothea Schröder/Shrader in the USA.

His future wife's family records are in Kessin, Blankenhagen, and Volkenshagen. Many years later, his daughter Louisa would marry Henry Brandt in the USA, who immigrated from Cammin b. Laage. These families all seem to have known each other before immigration.

---

According to family stories:

Christian's father Detloff Paap was married twice. Detloff only had two children. Detloff was a Cooper, maker of wooden barrels.

1. First wife Sophia Ruge, mother of Christian.
2. Second unknown wife, mother of half-brother Frederick.

---

This is the Schröder family immigration in 1862 with a person who is probably Christian Paap. Full name could be Johann Christian Paap or something similar. Christian was from Hinrichsdorf according to this passenger list.
[image]

This could be him as a sponsor for his future niece Dorothea born 1860.
[image]

In my research, Detloff is not a common given name, and Paap is not a common surname. So, a person with both these names would be a good candidate. I believe that this is his half-brother Frederick's birth.
[image]

And the marriage of his parents:
[image]

And two other children not mentioned in the family story. Paap is spelled differently in these records, but it seems to be the same person.
[image]
[image]

I can’t find the birth of Christian Paap (b1835) in this parish, or in many of the other parishes where I have found ancestors and relatives. If his birthdate is correct (Sep 1835), then something is strange. His father married only one month after Christian's birth. Maybe Christian was illegitimate?

I can't read the occupations. Does Detloff's record indicate that he was a Cooper or something similar?

Any other clues in the words I can't read?

Any suggestions on where to look next?